# Errors with RDD filter, map operations with Spark 2.1 and Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, apache-spark, filter, rdd

I am trying run the Logistic Regression example for Spark / Python given in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/mllib/logistic_regression.py and have successfully done so with Spark 1.6 and Python 2.7

Now I have to move it to Spark 2.1 and Python 3.5 ( 3.6 is incompatible) and I am using Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu 16.04

This code works fine

```
# Evaluate the model on training data
labelsAndPreds = modelInput.map(lambda p: (p.label, LRmodel.predict(p.features)))
print(labelsAndPreds.count())
print(labelsAndPreds)
print(labelsAndPreds.take(10))
```

and generates the following output

```
10000
PythonRDD[60] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48
[(0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0)]
```

obviously some of the v, p values are not the same and I need to trap the "model errors" by a filter that goes like this

```
Errors = labelsAndPreds.filter(lambda v, p: v != float(p))
print(Errors)
print(Errors.count())
```

the first two statements do not throw an error and gives the output

```
PythonRDD[57] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48
```

but the count() statement ( or even a collect()) statement gives a huge list of errors ending with

```
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'
```

I have tried to convert the output of the filter into a list

```
Errors = list(labelsAndPreds.filter(lambda v, p: v != float(p)))
```

but even this does not work and gives errors

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-a300023d2bc4> in <module>()
----> 1 Errors = list(labelsAndPreds.filter(lambda v, p: v != float(p)))
TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable
```

i have the same problem with a map function

```
checkData = modelInput.map(lambda p: (LRmodel.predict(p.features),p.label,  p.features))
checkNotCorrect = checkData.filter(lambda p,v,f : v!=p)
print(checkNotCorrect)
checkNotCorrect.count()
```

the first two statements do not throw any error,

```
PythonRDD[62] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48
```

but the moment I try to do anything with the resultant RDD, count(), collect() there is the same error

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-083cacc529f4> in <module>()
      2 checkNotCorrect = checkData.filter(lambda p,v,f : v!=p)
      3 print(checkNotCorrect)
----> 4 checkNotCorrect.count()

/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py in count(self)
   1039         3
   1040         """
-> 1041         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
   1042 
   1043     def stats(self):

/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py in sum(self)
   1030         6.0
   1031         """
-> 1032         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
   1033 
   1034     def count(self):

/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
    904         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
    905         # to the final reduce call
--> 906         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    907         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
    908 

/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
    807         """
    808         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 809             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    810         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    811 

/home/praxispark/spark21/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home/praxispark/spark21/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 42.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 42.0 (TID 47, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2407, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2407, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2407, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 346, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1041, in <lambda>
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1041, in <genexpr>
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'v' and 'f'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2407, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2407, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2407, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 346, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1041, in <lambda>
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/home/praxispark/spark21/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1041, in <genexpr>
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'v' and 'f'
```

Obviously I am doing something very stupid but I hope that some kind soul will spot the error in guide me in solving this problem. Thanks for reading so far ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, python doesn't play well with multiple valued lambdas

And you'll notice in the errors that it always mentions the additional arguments are "missing".

Simply use the tuple as-is in one parameter

```
filter(lambda x: x[0] != float(x[1]))
```

> I have tried to convert the output of the filter into a list

RDDs aren't Iterable, assuming the error states. You must call collect() or some equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Your RDD is a pair RDD, therefore `filter` expects a single argument of a tuple type. With Python 2 you could write:

```
checkNotCorrect = checkData.filter(lambda (p,v): v != p)
```

and the tuple will be unpacked for you into the `p` and `v` variables. This doesn't work in Python 3 though, because someone thought that tuple parameter unpacking is a really useless feature of Python 2 and suggested that it should be removed - see [PEP-3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/). The solution is to use the cumbersome index notation as presented in the other answer.

As for the errors:

```
Errors = labelsAndPreds.filter(lambda v, p: v != float(p))
```

This line does not throw an error since `filter()` is a **transformation**. Transformations do not get executed immediately, rather they create nodes in the lineage DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) representing the computation flow. Those get evaluated later on when an **action** triggers the actual computation. Note that `map()` too is a transformation and not an action.

```
print(Errors)
```

This one just prints a description of the `Errors` RDD object itself. Doesn't trigger any evaluation.

```
print(Errors.count())
```

`count()` is an **action**, which triggers execution of the nodes in the lineage DAG of that action. It is now that the lambda from the first line gets applied and therefore the error occurs.

Comment: your explanations are very helpful. learnt something new today, rather than blindly getting the code.